# Why can't I store information from this php object?

Tags: php

I am trying to store a specific string from a php object called `$json`, which is the json_decoded response from a web service I call.  In the course of debugging my problem, I echo out a serialized version of the string I am trying to store.  This displays `s:12:"392-445-9987";`, which is exactly what I want.  It is a string of length 12, and is the correct value.  However when I try to assign it to `$number` the code dies and never reaches the next line.

```
if(isset($json->AddressService->response->phones)) {
   echo "<textarea rows=50 cols=100>" . serialize($json->AddressService->response->phones[0]->phone_number) . "</textarea>";
   $number = $json->AddressService->response->phones[0]->phone_number;
   echo "I never reach this line!";
}
```

What am I missing?  How do I save the string to the variable?

Thank so much for any thoughts you have.

Comment: Do you get inside the `if` ? try to break the second line into a few statements and `echo` each of them.

Comment: Uhm... what's the error?  Invalid index?

Comment: Yes I get into the `if`.  that's where I get the phone number from.  but for some reason it dies at line 3.

Comment: can you `var_dump($json->AddressService->response->phones)` before the serializing and paste the result in the quesiton?

Comment: Yes, when I var_dump($json->AddressService->response->phones) it returns: `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#9 (8) { ["phone_index"]=> string(1) "1" ["phone_number"]=> string(12) "392-445-9987" ["country_code"]=> string(3) "USA" ["type_of_device"]=> string(5) "Phone" ["is_tty"]=> bool(false) ["is_mobile"]=> bool(true) ["is_unlisted"]=> bool(false) ["is_primary"]=> bool(true) } } `

Comment: @Landon I am checking the output in by browser, and it isn't reporting a error.  I checked the firebug console as well, and it doesn't report an error there either.  It simply dies with no report.  Is there a good way to check what the error is?

Comment: Firebug wouldn't be any help, this is most likely a server side issue.  your web server might be suppressing errors/warnings for your browser and dying silently which is annoying for dev reasons.  Put this above it, and it should echo useful info in the browser ... it doesn't look good in this comment, I put it below in an answer

Comment: What happens when you try doing: foreach ($json->AdressService->response->phones as $key) { $number=$key->phone_number } echo $number; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this above it to see php errors echoed in your browser:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: try to put a `$i=23/0;` to make sure the error reporting works, that should report a division of zero error

Comment: It returned: Warning: Division by zero in /opt/webroot/auth/contactInfo/index.php on line 5.

Comment: then I'm puzzled, the **only** way that second echo statement wouldn't get executed would be if the if above didn't return as true and the code block inside didn't run, **or** if there was a fatal error and the script died in the middle.